# IntelliJ doesn't show all classes in coverage view of my grails application

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, integration-testing, code-coverage

In my grails application i have some integration tests for each service. After the execution of those tests **with coverage** the IDE show me Coverage View, but some of those services don't appear in the tree of packages and classes of that view.

What i have to do for the Coverage View on IntelliJ show me all classes (even those with 0% cover) when i run my integration tests from my grails application?

The integration-tests are all in the same package, so as the services been tested. Some of those services appear, and some of them don't.

And sorry for the mistakes, that is my first question and English is not my primary language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve part of the problem. By accessing the Grails View, select the service test file I would like to see the coverage and run this test alone (right click> Run 'ServiceTest' With Coverage...) as an integration test.

The coverage view of IntelliJ showed me coverage percentage of the service I was testing the way I needed.

Answer (score -1):

1.Right click the folder you want to show code coverage;
2.And then select "Run tests in xxxx with code coverage".
3.And next it will pop up a window ask you whether add this file into "active xxxx" ;
4.click "add in active xxxx" and then it will show coverage in this folder.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVwu3.png)